# How to interpolate between lat, lon coordinates in rasterio

Tags: python, gis, geo, shapely, rasterio

I have a satellite image that I load into python with Rasterio, which gives the BoundingBox coordinates of the rectangular image, essentially (X1,Y1), (X2,Y2), (X3,Y3), (X4,Y4) in Decimal Degrees Latitude and Longitude.

The image itself is loaded in as an array, with width W pixels, and height H pixels.

I'm taking subsets of the image by number of pixels, and I want to find the corresponding lat,lon coordinates of these subsets.

Am I able to just use interpolation here? Or does it require some other method to account for earth curvature etc. The widest height/width size of the image is ~80km-100km.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can interpolate, the coordinates. Only when you [project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) your data to X-Y, earth's curvature is taken into account.

To create subsets while keeping coordinates, [rioxarray](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/getting_started/getting_started.html) is my favorite way of doing it.

```py
import xarray as xr

data = xr.open_dataarray(p)

# to create a selection
data[:, :100 :100]

# to get coordinates
data.coords['x'], data.coords['y']
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above, but ended up using rasterio's .xy function:

```
with rasterio.open(filepath) as src:
     src.xy(x_pixel_coord, y_pixel_coord)
```

This makes use of the lat/lon info contained within the file itself, and then the `xy` function gives the corresponding lat/lon for any pixel coords in that image